# What is the hidden value of the pointer/reference assigned to reference type variables?

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

```
int number = 1
```

The value of number is 1 because it is a value type

What is the actual value of the pointer that is assigned to reference type variables?

Is it an int or string? Or is it some bits? What would it look like if you write it out? Is it possible to assign a reference to a variable using that value?

```
Question harrysQuestion = new Question();
```

harrysQuestion is just a pointer or reference to the new Question. So what is the value of that pointer? The same value that is assigned to another Question variable if I do this:

```
Question harrysQuestionAgain = harrysQuestion;
```

Is it a number that points to some position in my computers memory? Is it an actual C# value variable behind the scenes?

Comment: It's a .NET abstraction that you shouldn't need to worry about.  The actual underlying value might even change behind the scenes while .NET is performing memory management.  In theory different runtime implementations could do entirely different things with it.  Do you have a more specific question about why you might need to worry about it - is there a reason you may need to know, or just curious (which is also fine!)?

Comment: @James I'm just curios/want to learn more about how code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a number that points to some position in my computers memory?

Conceptually, references and pointers are separate but related. In reality they are *virtually* interchangeable, with the distinction that the GC knows how to walk and fixup references (garbage collection etc), but not pointers (and there are other things about how `fixed` works in terms of a hack in the value, allowing a reference *value* found on the stack to be interpreted as "pinned" cheaply). In reality, they are *so close* to each-other in all implementations (for performance reasons) that you can think of them as *kinda* the same.

It is very rare that you'd actually want to *get* the "value" of a reference (rather than *dereferencing it*), and unless you pin the object first you need to be very careful about doing so as the address can change (and the pointer version *will not be corrected*). The need for this use-case actually *increases* slightly with the upcoming "pipelines" work, so the corefxlab / myget version of the `Unsafe` utility type actually provides some methods to facilitate the exchange of references / pointers (including interior pointers/references into objects), but: unless you're doing something low level you'll probably never need that.

---

Per request (comments): I mentioned "pinning" and "fixed" - the problem here is that .NET has a "compacting" garbage collector, which is allowed to *move objects around* at runtime, as long as it promises to fix all the references *and* make sure that you never notice this from managed code. What it *doesn't* promise is to fix pointers. So: if you're going to be looking at any object *as a pointer*, you need to tell the runtime (and in particular: the garbage collector) to **not move that object** at all, or at least until you tell it that you're done. This is what "pinning" is. There are two ways to "pin":

- for long-term pins (typically of things like `byte[]` buffers that you're going to store as a field in an object and pass to unmanaged code as a pointer), you can take a `GCHandle` against an object, which gets logged in a global structure that the GC knows to look at
- for short-term pins of references that are *on a stack*, the `fixed` keyword does some voodoo that lets the GC (which always looks at every stack) know that a reference - and thus the object *referred to* (the object at that address) - should be considered pinned, *without* needing to constantly add/remove to a global structure

---

As a perhaps interesting side note: "interior references" and references to value types are a concept that *only exists* on the stack - not as *fields* on a type that could end up on the heap (which means any `class` or `struct` except for the new `ref struct` concept). They work the same as regular references, but the target of those references are the *contents themselves*, not the start of the object header. That means that

```
var fieldReference = ref this._someField;
```

or

```
SomeOtherMethod(ref this._someField);
```

or

```
SomeOtherMethod(ref someArray[index]);
```

work inside a method *as long as that interior reference is only on the stack* (i.e. no `async` / `yield` / captured-variables / etc); the GC is happy to do the overhead of resolving interior pointers to objects *but only* for the stacks - to reduce the overall scale of the work involved.

Comment: +1, though maybe briefly describe just what pinning does, as it seems to me that the movement of objects by GC is one of the biggest differences between a .NET reference and a pointer in an unmanaged language (or even a reference in such a language) at that level (albeit, a level one would pretty much never deal with).

Comment: Those "interior references", actually `ref` in general, are implemented by what's called in CIL "managed pointers". I think saying the GC doesn't handle pointers is misleading. The GC only doesn't handle unmanaged pointers.

Comment: @hvd indeed, but in C# terms, they're references (`ref`); the main reason I didn't want to say "unmanaged pointers" is because that then gets people thinking about "unmanaged memory", and of course we can have "unmanaged pointers" (in CIL terms) that are (essentially) interior references to managed objects. But you're absolutely right. The few times that a C# dev thinks in terms of "pointers", they're really talking "unmanaged pointers" (CIL), so I'm being ... deliberately hand-wavey.